# install ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 3181?

Tags: dell, 18.10, chromebook, inspiron

I wish to use Dell's Chromebook Inspiron 3181 (ChromeOS) to install ubuntu-only. Is there any detailed information to do just that - w/o the need to tamper with the BIOS?

I might add that, in past, I did install Ubuntu OS on two Acer (710 & 720) Chromebooks using Mrchrombox coreboot bios which worked well. Both LTs required flashing the BIOS - replaced with open source ones from this site.
https://mrchromebox.tech/

Therefore, I am well familiar with the installation of Ubuntu. It is With Dell Chromebook HW which I am not sure yet.

Comment: Why not download Ubuntu and try it on your machine.  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install   Your machine is just a cheap x86 (celeron)

Comment: All I like to know if the Dell Bios for this model accept new OS w/o the need to flash it with open source BIOS like coreboot offered by Mrchrombox.tech